# facebook login button cannot be customized? swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

```
    faceBookRegisterButton.delegate = self
    faceBookRegisterButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
    faceBookRegisterButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "facebook_filled"), forState: .Normal)
    faceBookRegisterButton.frame = CGRectMake(faceBookRegisterButton.frame.origin.x, faceBookRegisterButton.frame.origin.y, 107, 107)
    faceBookRegisterButton.setTitle("", forState: .Normal)
    print(faceBookRegisterButton.titleLabel?.text)
```

faceBookRegisterButton is a UIButton whose class is FBSDKLoginButton. However, I find when I customize the button it does not work, the setBackgroundImage works, however, frame and setTitle does not work why? [Now, the screenshot is like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJUWs.png)

I really want to delete that Log in with and resize the button. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) No need to do the fancy stuff just take a button in `storyBoard` .It will be a simple custom button which can be customized as you want.

> note - No need to change the class of button, it will UIButton

2)Drag the action in the ViewController call below method

```
   func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
            println("User Logged In")

            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                // Process error
            }
            else if result.isCancelled {
                // Handle cancellations
            }
            else {
                // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
                // should check if specific permissions missing
                if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")
                {
                     // Do work
        self.returnUserData()

                }
            }   
        }
```

Comment: If I delete the class for that button, it will come with some error{2016-02-12 22:08:28.434 bliss[69035:5342746] -[UIButton setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe903745af0
2016-02-12 22:08:28.437 bliss[69035:5342746] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe903745af0'}

Comment: Please check where you are setting delegate on that button..also remove this line

Comment: As UIButton has no delegate property,it will give unrecognized selector error

Comment: Thank you, I solve it! Because the YouTube video tells me that I need to set a class to that UIButton, so I misunderstand the api of facebook. Any way thank you.